# existing properties doesn't work anymore post Spring boot v3.2.1 migration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-cloud, spring-boot-3

I am in the process of moving all my existing spring boot applications from version `2.7.4` to `3.2.1`. All the applications have more than 50+ properties defined in the `application.yml` file. there are 4 different property files based on environments.

It looks like a lot of existing properties have either been deprecated or removed in Spring Boot 3. for example:

1. `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator` property is removed
2. `server.max.http.header.size` has been moved to `server.max-http-request-header-size`

is there any automated way to figure out which existing properties need to be migrated to new ones?

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily handled in an automated way by adding following dependency

for Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

For Gradle:

```
 runtime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-properties-migrator")
```

Run `mvn clean package` and it will generate a report for all the dependencies needing an update or which can be removed.

This is explained in detailed on this article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-properties-migrator

Answer (score 0):

Spring provide this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-properties-migrator to help migrate application properties. I never used it honestly. In addition, for each major version, Spring provide a `Configuration Changelog` where there are the following sections:

- `Deprecated in 3.x.x`
- `New in 3.x.x`

Here the links for your use case from 2.7.x to 3.2.x:

- Springboot 2.7.x -> 3.0.0: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Configuration-Changelog
- Springboot 3.0.x -> 3.1.0: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.1.0-Configuration-Changelog
- Springboot 3.1.x -> 3.2.0: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2.0-Configuration-Changelog